# Wann benutzt man welche Präposition?

Tags: preposition

Ich habe eine bzw. mehrere Fragen hinsichtlich des Gebrauchs verschiedener Präpositionen. Ich brauche das nicht wirklich selbst, da Deutsch meine Muttersprache ist und ich die Präpositionen zu Wörtern einfach aus dem Alltag weiß. Meine amerikanische Freundin hat jedoch Probleme damit und ich bin mir nicht so sicher, wie man das am besten erklärt, damit sie es gut versteht.

Es geht um die lokalen Präpositionen, vor allem: "an", "in", "zu" und "bei".

Ich habe ihr bereits erklärt, dass es **an** einem Ort und **bei** einer Person heißt. Außerdem kann man in den sinnvollen Fällen anstatt "an" auch "in" benutzen.

Z. B.:

> Ich besuche den Elternabend an/in der Schule.

Man kann in dem nächsten Fall kein "in" benutzen:

> Ich gehe an den Strand.

"In" ist hier falsch, weil das bedeuten würde, dass man seinen Kopf in den Sand stecken würde oder so.

Nächstes Beispiel:

> Wir fahren an einen See.

"In" geht nicht, weil man mit dem Auto ja nicht direkt in den See hinein fährt.

> Ich gehe in den See.

Hier geht kein "an", weil man direkt in den See geht, ins Wasser.

Soweit habe ich das erklärt, dann benutzt man manchmal ja auch "zu(m)". Dazu ist mir aber einfach keine "Regel" eingefallen und auch die obere Erklärung ist ja jetzt auch keine offizielle Regel oder so.

Wie kann man das am besten schlüssig erklären?

Comment: Ich bin überrascht, dass ich dazu keine allgemeingültige Frage hier auf GL finde, aber es gibt zumindest einige verwandte Fragen: http://german.stackexchange.com/q/8479/1224# http://german.stackexchange.com/q/25807/1224

Comment: Wenn ich es mir recht überlege, ist deine Frage doch ein Duplikat zur ersteren verlinkten Frage in meinem vorherigen Kommentar? — Der Titel deiner Frage lässt übrigens eine sehr weitgefächerte Frage vermuten, was übrigens unmöglich wäre, zu beantworten.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zunächst sollte man mal festhalten, dass Präpositionen eine Teilmenge der Adpositionen sind, allerdings sind im Deutschen die überwiegende Mehrheit aller Adpositionen Präpositionen.

Diese Arten von Adpositionen gibt es:

- Präposition
  steht *vor* dem Begriff den sie regiert

  > *jenseits* des Flusses
- Postposition
  steht *hinter* dem Begriff den sie regiert

  > der Einfachheit *halber*
- Ambiposition
  kann wahlweise *vor* oder *hinter* dem Begriff stehen und wird dann auch je nach konkreter Ausprägung als Prä- oder Postposition bezeichnet

  > des Kindes *wegen* (Postposition)
  >   *wegen* des Kindes (Präposition)
- Zirkumposition
  besteht aus zwei Teilen, die den Begriff umklammern

  > *um* des Friedens *willen*
- Interposition
  hat zwei gleiche Wörter die sie regiert, und steht zwischen ihnen

  > Stein *auf* Stein

---

Wann man welche Adposition verwenden muss, muss man Wort für Wort lernen. So wie man bei Substantiven lernen muss was ein *Hirschschlögel* oder ein *Mumpitz* ist, oder bei Verben was *titrieren* und *missen* bedeuten, muss man das auch bei allen anderen Wortarten lernen.

Und so muss man bei den Adpositionen eben einzeln lernen, wofür man sie gebrauchen kann. Bei den Adpositionen kommt noch hinzu, dass man auch lernen muss, ob sie vor oder hinter den Begriff gestellt werden müssen auf den sie sich beziehen (fast immer davor), und welchen grammatischen Fall sie verlangen.

Beispiele:

> »*längs* der Achse«: Genitiv (Präposition)
>   »*von* seiner Geburt *an*«: Dativ (Zirkumposition)
>   »den Kindern *zuliebe*«: Akkusativ (Postposition)

---

Bewährt hat es sich, die Adpositionen in Bedeutungsgruppen einzuteilen, und die Wörter einer Gruppe zu lernen und zu üben, und sich dann der nächsten Gruppe zuzuwenden.

Bedeutungsgruppen sind:

- lokale Adpositonen (wo? woher? wohin?)

  > *außerhalb* der Schachtel
  >   *aus* der Türkei
  >   *zwischen* den Augen
  >   *zwischen* die Augen
- temporale Adpositionen (wann?)

  > *außerhalb* der Öffnungszeiten
  >   *am* Dienstag
- kausale Adposition (warum?)

  > *unerachtet* der Anstrengung
  >   *bezüglich* Ihrer Anfrage
- modale Adposition (wie?)

  > *abzüglich* der Spesen
  >   *auf* Deutsch

Natürlich habe ich nur ganz wenige Beispiele angeführt. Ich vermute, dass es mehr als 100 verschiedene Adpositionen im Deutschen gibt.

Wie man am Beispiel von *außerhalb* sehen kann, gibt es Adpositionen, die man auf mehrere Weisen verwenden kann, und das Beispiel »zwischen« zeigt auch, dass es Präpositionen gibt, die je nach Bedeutung unterschiedliche grammatische Fälle verlangen können:

> Ilse hat zwischen den Augen ein Muttermahl. (wo? Dativ)
>   Der Mörder schoss ihm genau zwischen die Augen. (wohin? Akkusativ)

Aber die Grundaussage bleibt:

**Man muss einzeln pro Begriff lernen, wofür er eingesetzt werden kann.**

Da es so viele verschiedene Adpositionen gibt, würde es den Umfang dieser Antwort sprengen, wenn ich hier jetzt jedes einzelne Wort behandeln würde.